# Google Play doesn't show number of downloads for my android app

Tags: android, google-play

I published my first Android App 4 days ago. I can see the number of downloads on [play.google.com](http://play.google.com) which is 10 but I don't see any option at all in the play store on my cell phone. It only shows three option 1) ratings 2) catagory 3) similar. Whereas I do see a **download count** for other Apps. I am a beginner and that is my first ever App so I am sorry for asking a silly question, is there something I need to mention in my code? Would anyone please help me make that option visible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post a link to your app?

Comment: @lamsomeone https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cooljbd.kingofcooljbd

Comment: It shows "more than 0 downloads" for me

Comment: Is there any reason I don't see that option? Is there something I need to enable or disable? It just shows "3.5 stars", "Entertainment", "Similar". Usually the first option is "Downloads"

Comment: You should be able to see it in the play store just under your app's icon

Comment: Yes but I don't see it. Does it have anything to to with the country?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

It takes time to show up, Google verifies the download count before they put it up. If you check your app now, it has 500 downloads. And It won't show a badge if it's under 100 downloads always.

Comment: I published 2 apps a year ago and I still don't have a counter.

Comment: Also reviews from other users are not showing.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.festinger.autovolume&hl=en&gl=US